# Change CSS style with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written this small function in Javascript for changing the padding on an element in HTML. It works well, however, I wonder if there is a better way to write it without so many *if* statements?

```
  window.addEventListener("resize", navPadding); 

  function navPadding() {
    let width = window.innerWidth;

    if(width < 1200){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "unset"
    } else 

    if(width > 1200 && width < 1300){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 19% 0 5.5%"
    } else 

    if(width > 1300 && width < 1400){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 19% 0 8.5%"
    } else 

    if(width > 1400 && width < 1500){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 19% 0 11.5%"
    } else 

    if(width > 1500 && width < 1600){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 19% 0 14%"
    } else 

    if(width > 1600 && width < 1700){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 19% 0 16%"
    } else 

    if(width > 1700 && width < 1800){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 19% 0 18%"
    } else 

    if(width > 1800 && width < 1900){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 19% 0 19%"
    } else 

    if(width > 1900 && width < 2000){
      navDesktop.style.padding = "0 20% 0 21%"
    };
  };

  navPadding();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That huge `if/else` conditional could be converted to `for` loop with `break` statement.
Assuming `1200` and `2000` as range's lower/upper boundaries.

Padding *bottom-left* value has the most variation depending on `width`.
That fixed variation can be declared as predefined array:

```
const paddingSteps = [5.5, 8.5, 11.5, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21];
```

---

The final concise implementation:

```
const paddingSteps = [5.5, 8.5, 11.5, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21];

function navPadding() {
    let width = window.innerWidth;

    if (width < 1200) {
        navDesktop.style.padding = "unset";
        return;
    }
    for (i = 1200; i <= 2000; i += 100) {
        if (width >= i && width <= i + 100) {
            padRight = (width >= 1900) ? 20 : 19;
            navDesktop.style.padding = `0 ${padRight}% 0 ${paddingSteps[i % 1200 / 100]}%`;
            break;
        }
    }
}

navPadding();
```

Comment: Very clever, thank you very much! It works as expected if I just plug it in my code and cuts the number of lines in half.